# How to find the best combination to minimize the total distance in all groups of points

Tags: grouping, combinations, cluster-analysis

Given 4n+k points with the position (x,y) (or (x,y,z) for a 3D case), where n=1,2,3,...; k∈{0,1,2,3}.
Group the points into n-k groups of 4 points, and k groups of 5 points.
A group centroid is the mean position of the 4(or 5) points in the group.

How to effectively get the best combination to minimize the sum of the distance of each point to its own group centroid?

Brutal enumeration is the only way I've achieve to get the best combination. However brutal force only works when n is quite small because of the computational limitation.

I also tried K-Means clustering and genetic algorithm, but neither of them nor the combination of these two algorithms can guarantee the best combination.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem supposedly is NP-hard you won't be able to find an algorithm that *guarantees* to find the optimum and that runs in acceptable time on large data.

You'll have to settle for an approximation such as kmeans.

Comment: How can we prove this is a NP-Hard?

Comment: Show that you can solve another NP-hard problem such as 3SAT if you can solve this in P time.